# How to query GROUP BY Month in a Year

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer.
I essentially have a table of pictures that holds the columns:

[DATE_CREATED(date), NUM_of_PICTURES(int)]

and if I do a select *, I would get an output similar to:

```
01-May-12    12
02-May-12    15
03-May-12    09
...
...
01-Jun-12    20
...
etc.
```

I am trying to aggregate these sums of pictures into MONTHLY numbers instead of DAILY.

I've tried doing something like:

```
select Month(DATE_CREATED), sum(Num_of_Pictures))
from pictures_table
group by Month(DATE_CREATED);
```

This outputs an error:

```
ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 9
```

Do I have the Month function wrong?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I would be inclined to include the year in the output.  One way:

```
select to_char(DATE_CREATED, 'YYYY-MM'), sum(Num_of_Pictures)
from pictures_table
group by to_char(DATE_CREATED, 'YYYY-MM')
order by 1
```

Another way (more standard SQL):

```
select extract(year from date_created) as yr, extract(month from date_created) as mon,
       sum(Num_of_Pictures)
from pictures_table
group by extract(year from date_created), extract(month from date_created)
order by yr, mon;
```

Remember the order by, since you presumably want these in order, and there is no guarantee about the order that rows are returned in after a group by.

Comment: what does the 1 and 2 stand for in the order by?

Comment: The 1 and 2 refer to the columns being sorted, the first and second.  You could also say "yr, mon".

Comment: Also if there's an index on date_created the second option works better

Comment: Wow! The 1, 2 etc can also be used on GROUP BY

Comment: @Ajoy  . . .  I don't think so, at least not in Oracle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Right. I would rather say that this works in PostgreSQL 9.2

Comment: Still bad practice to use result column numbers. Difficult to maintain.

Comment: @Manoj . . . You would need to be more specific about what does not work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry I whad primary ids for id column while date column had several dates which belong to group of single year in my select statement I was trying to get ids and date and use groupd which does not work and this is expected behavior

Comment: @Manoj . . . Perhaps you should ask a question.

Answer (score 22):

For Oracle:

```
select EXTRACT(month from DATE_CREATED), sum(Num_of_Pictures)
from pictures_table
group by EXTRACT(month from DATE_CREATED);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am doing like this in MSSQL

Getting Monthly Data:

```
 SELECT YEAR(DATE_CREATED) [Year], MONTH(DATE_CREATED) [Month], 
     DATENAME(MONTH,DATE_CREATED) [Month Name], SUM(Num_of_Pictures) [Pictures Count]
    FROM pictures_table
    GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_CREATED), MONTH(DATE_CREATED), 
     DATENAME(MONTH, DATE_CREATED)
    ORDER BY 1,2
```

Getting Monthly Data using PIVOT:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT YEAR(DATE_CREATED) [Year], 
       DATENAME(MONTH, DATE_CREATED) [Month], 
       SUM(Num_of_Pictures) [Pictures Count]
      FROM pictures_table
      GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_CREATED), 
      DATENAME(MONTH, DATE_CREATED)) AS MontlySalesData
PIVOT( SUM([Pictures Count])   
    FOR Month IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December])) AS MNamePivot
```

Answer (score -3):

For MS SQL you can do this.

```
    select  CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DateTyme) as VARCHAR) +'/'+ 
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DateTyme) as VARCHAR) as 'Date' from #temp
    group by Name, CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DateTyme) as VARCHAR) +'/'+
 CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DateTyme) as VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```
    select FK_Items,Sum(PoiQuantity) Quantity  from PurchaseOrderItems POI
    left join PurchaseOrder PO ON po.ID_PurchaseOrder=poi.FK_PurchaseOrder
    group by FK_Items,DATEPART(MONTH, TransDate)
```