# Count business days in month excluding holidays

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table.

TableA

```
DaysInMonth    CalDate    CalendarMonth  MonthEndInd  CalDateMonth  WorkDay  HolidayInd
   31          3/26/2018     MAR 2018      N             3/31/2018     1         N
   31          3/25/2018     MAR 2018      N             3/31/2018     0         N
```

How can I calculate the number of WorkDays in a month?
I'm not sure where to start, so I don't have any work to show.

Expected output

```
DaysInMonth    CalDate    CalendarMonth  MonthEndInd  CalDateMonth  WorkDay  HolidayInd   WorkDaysInMonth
   31          3/26/2018     MAR 2018      N             3/31/2018     1         N
   31          3/25/2018     MAR 2018      N             3/31/2018     0         N
```

SQL I have the below but how can I add this to my query

```
SELECT COUNT(*),C.CALENDAR_MONTH FROM HUM.CALENDAR C WHERE 1=1 AND C.WORKDAY = 1 GROUP BY C.CALENDAR_MONTH
```

Comment: What's the definition of a "work day"? Days in a month minus holidays? Just Monday-Friday?

Comment: @Strikegently I'm going to guess it's defined by the "WorkDay" field specified in the table against each day.

Comment: That definition is in the column WorkDate. 1 = a work day.

Comment: Anyway you can calculate it using a SUM on the WorkDay column (and obviously restrict the query to a particular month)

Comment: "how can I add this to my query"...it already _is_ a query...not sure what you mean. And yeah that should work - counting where WorkDay = 1 would be the same as SUM without that extra clause

Comment: Yes. was looking for a way around using the group by feature.

Comment: Well if you only want it for a single month you could avoid the group by. But if you want to report many months together then you need it. Otherwise the aggregate function (SUM or COUNT) can't be used, because there would be too many rows.

Comment: Group by month and do a count `WHERE "WorkDay" = 1`. You can select the count with `AS "WorkDaysInMonth"` to include it in your results. Reference for group-by-month in Oracle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531785/how-to-query-group-by-month-in-a-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an analytic function:

```
SELECT c.*,
       SUM( WorkDay ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CalendarMonth ) AS WorkDaysInMonth
FROM   Calendar C;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd93e/5)

Answer (score 0):

In much the same way as SUM you can also use COUNT if you want to limit it to just working days;

```
SELECT c.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY calendarmonth ORDER BY calendarmonth) WDIM
FROM   calendar
WHERE  workday = 1
```

Depends how you want to use it I guess.